# Google Consider HTTPs over HTTP - How to redirect https to http without losing traffic

Tags: 301-redirect, https, security-certificate

I have not installed SSL nor enable on my website, however the hosting companies did it.

Now Google started crawling https pages over http.

I have uninstall the ssl form Hosting Cpanel today.

Wanted to know whether:

1) Shall i redirect https to http using .htaccess?
2) Shall wait for Google to re-crawl the website, since i have uninstall the SSL from my website.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to run the site without SSL? Google rewards for SSL. If the site is slow then I recommend you choose a new host.

But to answer your question you can **NOT** redirect HTTPS to HTTP if you have uninstalled the SSL cert. This is due to the fact that in order to redirect a user from HTTPS to HTTP... HTTPS must be working.

Sadly you made the mistake of uninstalling SSL when really you didn't need to at all, if you want `HTTP://` rather than `HTTPS://` then all you needed to do was setup the redirect, users and bots would be forced to use the site as `HTTP://`.

Comment: My site is about 3+ year old and it's a blog. So, don't want to use SSL.

So, what's the option? 

Since, I already uninstall the ssl, will Google start re-crawling from httpS to http?

Comment: What's the age of site got to do with anything? SSL is for users, not you. Google won't be able to recrawl the HTTPS because you broke it, so you will need to login to Google Search Console, add the `HTTP://` property and `HTTPS://` then tell Google your [prefered version](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en). Note that anyone linking to you using `HTTPS://` will not pass juice to `HTTP://` without a working redirect and also it will take Google longer to un-index HTTPS and index HTTP again.

Comment: It'll take about 2-4 weeks for Google to re-index the site on the different domain since it will purposely wait and there's no way around this. That's why you setup a redirect while you wait, you don't lose traffic, but since you don't have SSL, you can't do that.

Comment: The SSL certificate automatically re-installed on to the hosting Cpanel.

However hosting team not able to redirect https to http using 301.

And now they are suggesting it to remove SSL itself so that Google will automatically start crawling the http version.

What things to consider while shifting from http to https, since i don't want to loose traffic.

Comment: If your host can not do simple things like redirecting HTTPS to HTTP then you with the wrong host. Its one of the easiest things to do and takes 30 seconds. By default MOD_REWRITE is enabled in cPanel, that's all you need to redirect HTTPS to HTTP using htaccess.